# Azure Queue Updating invisible message for first time fails. Succeeds once message becomes visible

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

1. I created an invisible message using AddMessage. Invisible for 6 hours. Azure Storage explorer shows "0 of 1 message". It means the message was accepted by the Queue service, but not yet visible.
2. Saving the messageId and Pop Receipt after the successful addMessage call.
3. From other application, when I tried to UpdateMessage using above messageId and PopReceipt. It throws an error
   "404 message not found".
4. Once the same message becomes visible, UpdateMessage was successful with the same messageId and PopReceipt. Now I changed its content and visibility - to make it invisible for further 4 hours.
   The Azure Storage Explorer is now showing "0 of 1 messages"
   After this UpdateMessage, a new PopReceipt was generated.
5. From other application, I tried to update an invisible Message with the new PopReceipt. This time UpdateMessage was successful.

It looks like UpdateMessage is failing for the first time invisible message. Once message becomes visible to the Queue, then subsequent UpdateMessage calls are successful regardless of visibility of the message.

Any idea what's going on here, or am I missing something?

Update:

One more observation:

1.

```
queue.AddMessage(msg, System.Nullable(), invisibleTime) 
queue.UpdateMessage(msg, invisibleTime,...) 
//save msg.messageId and msg.PopReceipt to be used later
```

2. From other application:

   ```
   msg = new CloudQueueMessage(mid, popReceipt) //saved vals from (1)
   queue.UpdateMessage(msg, newInvisibleTime, ...)
   ```

Here UpdateMessage allowed me to update an invisible message.

If I removed **UpdateMessage** call from step (1), then in the step (2), the **UpdateMessage** call would fail with an error `404 message not found`

Comment: Not sure what, exactly, you're expecting, but... it's working as designed: you cannot work with invisible messages. Exactly as you've experienced.

Comment: I'm trying to design scheduled tasks, and need to support the functionality of changing the schedule. 
The PopReceipt allows to update invisible message - e.g. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-queues-new-feature-pop-receipt-on-add-message/

Step (5) mentioned above allows me to update the invisible message.

Comment: Please *edit your question* rather than dumping more details into comments. Especially code, which is completely unreadable as unformatted text in comments.